# Google Cloud Storage get_blob call results in stale socket connections

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get a blob object from a google storage bucket using python:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_bucket = storage.Client(project).bucket(bucket_name)
blob = storage_bucket.get_blob("some-blob-path")
```

Doing this results in stale socket connections that are first in ESTABLISHED status and then switch to CLOSE_WAIT status after a while:

```
python3.6 33713 xxxxx   14u    IPv6 0xfed2daa65e1d7abf        0t0        TCP [2601:646:9500:d6cf:2061:3a97:e840:70e4]:52658->sfo03s08-in-x0d.1e100.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
python3.6 33713 xxxxx   15u    IPv6 0xfed2daa65e1d807f        0t0        TCP [2601:646:9500:d6cf:2061:3a97:e840:70e4]:52659->nuq04s29-in-x0a.1e100.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
python3.6 33713 xxxxx   16u  KQUEUE                                          count=0, state=0xa
python3.6 33713 xxxxx   18u    IPv6 0xfed2daa66543b07f        0t0        TCP [2601:646:9500:d6cf:2061:3a97:e840:70e4]:52664->sfo03s08-in-x0d.1e100.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
python3.6 33713 xxxxx   19u    IPv6 0xfed2daa66543aabf        0t0        TCP [2601:646:9500:d6cf:2061:3a97:e840:70e4]:52665->nuq04s29-in-x0a.1e100.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
python3.6 33713 xxxxx   20u    IPv6 0xfed2daa65e1ccf3f        0t0        TCP [2601:646:9500:d6cf:2061:3a97:e840:70e4]:52670->sfo03s08-in-x0d.1e100.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
python3.6 33713 xxxxx   21u    IPv6 0xfed2daa65e1cacbf        0t0        TCP [2601:646:9500:d6cf:2061:3a97:e840:70e4]:52671->nuq04s29-in-x0a.1e100.net:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

To be precise, each call to get_blob results in two of those CLOSE_WAIT statuses. When this happens too many times in the running code, I end up getting "too many connections open" error, after which the only solution would be to restart my daemon.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Is there a specific clean-up that I should do? (just deleting the object does not work)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution for this, as the [classes you are using](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/client.html) don't have a proper `close` method or similar, is to raise a issue in the [official Github repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues), as they are the maintainers of this library, and they are better suited to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you. I already reported this issue to:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78318918

and they also recommended me to report it in the corresponding github repository. It seems that this problem arises due to an issue in urllib3 though.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you accept the answer? For future reference of the community.